# Applying OR condition on SUM function in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 columns named `Debit` and `Credit`. I want to get the value from one column and put in the third column, `Balance`. I want to apply a condition that if `Debit` contains any value, it should be put in the `Balance` column, and if `Credit` has something, then it should insert that value in the column, but if both have some values in them, then only one should go there, either `Debit` or `Credit`.

```
Debit    Credit     Balance
------------------------------
1000     NULL       1000
2200     NULL       2200
NULL     3000       3000
1500     1500       1500
```

Query:

```
SELECT 
       Debit, Credit, SUM(Credit|Debit) AS Balance
FROM Table
```

Comment: `if both have some values in them than only one should go there either Debit of Credit.` ... please explain this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For instance `COALESCE()`  is enough

```
SELECT Debit, Credit, COALESCE(Credit, Debit) AS Balance
FROM Table
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly, you are looking for something like this.

```
SELECT Debit, Credit,     
(
 CASE WHEN Credit IS NOT NULL THEN Credit      
 ELSE Debit 
 END
)  AS Balance
FROM [Table]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
declare @tab table(Debit int,Credit int)

insert into @tab
select 1000  ,   NULL
union all   
select 2200   ,  NULL  
union all 
select NULL  ,   3000  
union all 
select 1500  ,   1500   


SELECT Debit, Credit,
CASE WHEN Debit is null then Credit
 WHEN Credit is null then Debit else Debit end AS Balance
FROM @tab
```

output

```
Debit   Credit  Balance
1000    NULL    1000
2200    NULL    2200
NULL    3000    3000
1500    1500    1500
```